# Job Priority in Batch Jobs

Tags: priority, batch-jobs

I do not have administrative privileges on the cluster that i am using. I'd like to prioritize some of the jobs that I have submitted. How do i incorporate that into my batch file:

```
 #!/bin/bash
#$ -V
#$ -cwd
#$ -N name
#$ -y
#$ -pe orte 1 
#$ -o output

~/ct.exe
```

Comment: That would depend entirely on your cluster, how it's configured, what privileges the cluster admin has granted to users, what job scheduler it uses (pbs? torque? slurm?).  You haven't provided any details...and even if you had, the only good answer would still be "ask your cluster admins".

Comment: What is your script trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to have the control of priority using a standard user you will need to reduce the priority of the less important scripts, so the most important will run faster.

For example:

mylowpriorityscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
renice 20 $$
#lot of nice things
```

mymediumpriorityscript

```
#!/bin/bash
renice 10 $$
#lot of nice things
```

myhighpriorityscript

```
#!/bin/bash
renice 00 $$
#lot of nice things
```

And configure the priority of your shell in .bashrc to 10, so you can manage the subprocesses to other priorities using "nice" like:

.bashrc

```
renice 10 $$
```

Comment: A note: some subprocesses will not run at the same priority of the main script so you can call the subprocesses with nice -n10 command.

Answer (score 0):

Use nice if you want to run the process and renice if you want to change priority for a running process